# Can't make text equal string

Tags: java

I can't make my string entireFileText test to see if it is the same as Email.  I think I'm missing something...

if(entireFileText == Email) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Welcome back!", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("oops");
                        }

Comment: You must write this code `entireFileText.equals(Email)` instead of `entireFileText==Email`

Answer (score 1):

```
entireFileText.equals(Email)
```

check contents instead of string references.